# How to show a component n times in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, loops, native

I have a flatlist that shows some firebase docs, every doc contains a name and a value, I need to show that name n times, where n=value.

```
<FlatList 
               data = {WorkoutList}
               keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
               renderItem={({item}) => 
                        <View>
                          <Text large light>{item.name}</Text>
                          <Text large light>{item.value} x</Text>
                        </View> }
/>
```

This will show

```
Paul
3
Mark
2
Luke 
1
```

I want to use the value informations to show this

```
Paul
Paul
Paul
Mark 
Mark
Luke
```

How can I show the 'item.name' text for 'item.value' times?

Answer (score 1):

Create another `list` and loop trough your initial one. Add to the `list` your data `n` according to the `value`. Use then the new `list` instead of your inital one.

```js
const list=[]

WorkoutList.map(i=>{

  const {id, name, value}=i

  for (let i = 0; i <= value; i++) {
    list.push({name, value:i,id:`${id}_${i}`})
  }

  return i
})

<FlatList 
               data = {list}
               keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
               renderItem={({item}) => 
                        <View>
                          <Text large light>{item.name}</Text>
                          <Text large light>{item.value} x</Text>
                        </View> }
/>
```